# # Error: line 1: ImportError: file <maya console> line 1: No module named HZrivet.UI

Tags: maya, pyc

My code was working well a day ago, but now it throws the following message:

> " # Error: line 1: ImportError: file  line 1: No module named HZrivet.UI "

This script is on .pyc format, it's a maya script. Also I have no knowledge in scripting.

Comment: Please provide more information about the problem

Comment: And 'your' code too...

Comment: python("import HZrivet.UI;HZrivet.UI.UI()");  it contains files on different folder  (__init__ )  (  convert ) ( nodes)  ( UI)   @ekostadinov @ hawk it would be really nice if i could fix this problem..

Comment: i tried to post the codes but it says too long so it needs to follow the link http://www.creativecrash.com/maya/script/hzrivet/comments#tabs